# Проблема с Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```
import kivy.app
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.ulx.button import Button
from kivy.ulx.widget import Widget
from kivy.ulx.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlaidout import Gridlaidout

class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        gl = Gridlaidout(cols = 4)

        gl.add_widget( Button(text="7") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="8") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="9") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="X") )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text="7") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="8") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="9") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="-") )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text="7") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="8") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="9") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="+") )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text="7") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="8") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="9") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text="=") )

        return gl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()

Не пойму что не так в данной проблеме
```

Ошибка:

```
$ Python Calc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy.app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: `pip install kivy`?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7:

```
pip install kivy
```

Python 3.x:

```
pip3 install kivy
```